# Distance in BlueJ

Tags: java, math, distance, bluej

OUTPUT should look like:

```
Enter the x and y coordinates of the first point: 3 -2
Enter the x and y coordinates of the second point: 9 2
Distance: 7.211
Positive Slope
```

I have updated the OP with what the code should look like if you're trying to find the distance.

**Here is what my code looks like right now:**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LineEvaluator
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter the x and y coordinates of the first point: ");
        double x1 = input.nextDouble();
        double y1 = input.nextDouble();

        System.out.print("Enter the x and y coordinates of the second point: ");
        double x2 = input.nextDouble();
        double y2 = input.nextDouble();

        double distance = Math.sqrt((x1 - x2) * (x1 - x2) + (y1 - y2) * (y1 - y2));
        System.out.printf("Distance: %.3f", distance);

        double slope = ((y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1));

        if(slope > 0)
        System.out.println("Positive Slope");
        else if(slope < 0)
        System.out.println("Negative Slope");
        else if(slope == 0)
        System.out.println("Horizontal");
    }
   }
```

Comment: Remove javascript tag.

Comment: Update your question a little: what exactly is wrong with what you have? Does it fail to compile, produce incorrect output...?

Comment: @ben I'm having trouble getting the output 7.211 when i enter those coordinates, instead i get 7.000. I also have no idea how to go about writing a code to tell me if the slope is either horizontal, vertical, negative or positive.

Comment: Replace x1 with d, x2 with f and so forth. Youve fallen victim to integer division, and it prints 7.000 because you cast the integer to a double.

Comment: For your other question, think about what it would mean to have each of those for words. Positive and negative are easy. Horizontal is too. Vertical is a little trickier but not too hard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So... First of all don't say int to double like that - go in the documentations and you'll find that `input.nextDouble()` exists and you can use that instead directly.

e.x.:

```
int y2 = input.nextInt();
double g = y2;
to...
double g = input.nextDouble()
```

Also, in your distance formula, you are using:

```
double distance = Math.sqrt((x1 - x2) * (x1 - x2) + (y1 - y2)*(y1 - y2));
```

If you're using that, please name your doubles to the proper names(`x1`, `x2`, etc...)

When you use `int`, it truncates. Read up on the differences: 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

Then, you can calculate the slope, say you store it in a variable `slope`.

When you're trying to find a slope that has infinite slope, you will get this error: `ArithmeticException`.

You can fix this by a `try catch`, surrounding the code you might divide by 0, and then `System.out.println("Vertical Line")` at that situation, or you could evaluate later and leave the `try catch` blank. Use this: `Double.isInfinite(double)` to evaluate later on.

Try catch example:

```
try{
    slope = (y2-y1)/(x2-x1)//if it's divide by zero then we will get this error
}catch(ArithmeticException e){
//Take care of the error as we discussed.
}
```

Use if-elses or switch statements to evaluate the slope:

```
if(slope > 0)
System.out.println("Positive slope")
else if(slope == 0)
System.out.println("Flat slope")...
```

Hope you got the idea.

Comment: Aww no you did it for him. Your answer is right but i was hoping to encourage OP to get there on his own with hints. Oh well. Upvote anyways :P

Comment: @BenKnoble My bad! I tried to point to some useful resources for him to read, but I know that people never read the sources I point to so I just tell him what's going on. I'll stray away from that in the future.

Comment: Its ok. Its a matter of opinion and style. As long as you arent helping the "hey heres this problem and i have nothing write all my code for me kthxbye" posters youre fine. It is an excellent answer.

Comment: Hey thanks man, really appreciate it. I decided to change it to `double x1 = input.nextDouble();` like you suggested. You lost me at the slope part, but i'll keep trying to figure it out. Thank you!

Comment: @StevenOrozco What do you need help with on that part?

Comment: @StevenOrozco I added an example of try-catch. Gotta go now though. Bye!